# Qt4.4 how to get the user settings path

Tags: c++, qt

- linux: `$HOME/.config`
- windows: `%APPDATA%`
- mac os: `$HOME/.config`

It can be set using http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#setPath, but it seems as I am not able to retrieve it.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlibraryinfo.html#location `QLibraryInfo::LibrariesPath` returns the system wide settings dir, which is not what I want.

Any ideas, or do I have to code it separately for each platform?

€: I want to create a sub directory, and store files into it. (You may punish me if this is a bad idea)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This might not answer your question directly: if you want to store per-user persistent data, shouldn't you use [QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#storageLocation) instead?

Comment: /home/user/.local/share/data// is looking good, although it seems not to be QT-specific.

Can anyone of you folks try this out on windoze and paste the result in here? That'd be great. thanks

Comment: On Windows XP, it should be something like "C:\Document and Settings\user\Local Settings\Application Data"

Answer (score 9):

This is a nasty workaround. First you create `QSettings`, then get its location.

```
QSettings cfg(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope,
       "organization", "application");

QString config_dir = QFileInfo(cfg.fileName()).absolutePath() + "/";
```

Credits go to the Qt Centre forum.

`QSettings` stores the default config in the user AppData directory. See documentation for [`QSettings`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html). Also this code instructs to store the config in the Ini file format.

Answer (score 5):

this works on both qt 4 and qt 5

```
QApplication::setApplicationName("MyApp");
QApplication::setOrganizationName("Me");

QString homePath;

#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    homePath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation);
#else
    homePath = QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation);
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't retrieve the path. In the Qt source, `src/corelib/io/qsettings.cpp`, there is a function to get the path:

```
static QString getPath(QSettings::Format format, QSettings::Scope scope)
{
    ...
```

but it's not accessible from code using Qt. You can't copy it and use it either, because it uses internal Qt globals to store the path...

EDIT: A solution was posted, using `QDesktopServices.storageLocation(QDesktopServices.DataLocation)` but it doesn't do exactly what the question was asking for, i.e. if I set a custom path using `QSettings.setPath()` it doesn't reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to know the settings path?  If you are going to put settings in it, you could use `QSettings`.  I could see making a subdirectory to hold various settings, but it seems like the easiest way would be to use `QSettings` directly.

Comment: It's potentially megabytes of data - this might slow down the whole settings thing.

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you at?
Might be related or not but in windows, the default is to write QSettings to the registry.

Comment: i want to store files in this directory. and i already know where they are on each platform, but is there a qt-way to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

I read more into the question than there was as it was originally posted. It is clearer after the edits. Ok, so can't you use..

```
QString QSettings::fileName () const
```

Returns the path where settings are written to using this `QSettings` object are stored.

On Windows, if the format is `QSettings::NativeFormat`, the return value is a system registry path, not a file path.

Comment: I don't want the home directory but the settings directory. examples given in the question.

Comment: The answer has been edited following clarification edits to the question.